# Iphone Error Terminating in response to SpringBoard's termination

Tags: iphone, debugging

I am testing my iphone application in the real phone and when my program running a few seconds.
   It exit automatically and show the message ' Terminating in response to SpringBoard's termination' and in console show program exit normally.It is wired, right?

I try a few times and happened every time. The program is very simple and have a scrollview and add about 50 subviews which created programaticaly not by interface builder.

Somethings already tried

1. Work well in simulator
2. Iphone is unlocked iphone 1G and OS 2.2

   How to debug this one? I can not trace any error code, because it say it is normal exit. status 0.

   Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing you're implementing a scrollView like the official apple photo app is. If that's the case then it may be that you're terminating because of memory problems. Try loading less of the subviews and if your application is running fine you need to find a way to have the subviews consume less memory, either via lazy loading or reduce what's being loaded into the memory.

Comment: yes,it is memory issue, I change it to 20 subviews, it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try placing A breakpoint in didReceiveMemoryWarning.  If it gets hit then I agree with david's comment.