# Terminating in response to SpringBoard's termination

Tags: iphone

I got this error in console .can any one tell me What kind of error is this.."**Terminating in response to SpringBoard's termination**".

Comment: Perhaps this [previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122901/iphone-error-terminating-in-response-to-springboards-termination) will help.

Answer (score 2):

that's when the app gets terminated by the ios for high memory usage or the springboard crashes( springboard is application that manages the other applications...aka..home screen), or you quit the app

if you have the device jailbroken you can get that pretty often

did you get the springboard restart alert?

Comment: that's because your device is jailbroken. i had the same problem with my app..and after i reseted the device to apple's ios i didn't have the problem anymore..so no need to worry..but to be sure look at memory management

Comment: are you sure! this is a memory problem?

Comment: as i said...cydia crashes some apps for no reason at all...on the other hand ios crases apps only for memory management..so if there's no problem with the memory...then its cydia's fault and you can't do anything about it

Comment: no its not Jailbroken.its branded new ipad2 and its using ios5.1 we periodically update it.

Comment: then you have a leak somewhere

Comment: we have used ARC and verified with static analyzer. We found the leaks at cfString and Malloc. But I doesn't know how to figure it out.

Comment: that's a complete other problem

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and accidentally it appeared that my code was still trying to do some action (in my case it was generating data for AudioUnit buffer) when I was quitting my app. I have just quit this generating in dealloc method and all looks much better. No warning.