# how to solve back button error in ios 7?

Tags: iphone, ios7, uinavigationcontroller

when i click back button then controller back to menu but crash the application ?

```
       -(void)launchselfEvalutionFromPresidentDetailViewController
        {
            Self_Evalution_Page *self_page=[[Self_Evalution_Page alloc]initWithNibName:@"Self_Evalution_Page" bundle:nil];

            [self.navigationController pushViewController:self_page animated:YES];

        }

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
        self.pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];

        self.pageController.dataSource = self;
        [[self.pageController view] setFrame: CGRectMake(0,[topBar bottom] + 5,320,500)];


        SelfEvalutionTableView *selfObj=[self viewControllerAtIndex:0];


        NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:selfObj];

        [self.pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

        [self addChildViewController:self.pageController];
        [[self view] addSubview:[self.pageController view]];
        [self.pageController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    }
```

i used this code for move forward .but i click back button application crash.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: when i click back button application hang on left menu .

Comment: That doesn't give the error message. Look at the debugger, what's the kind of error message? EXC_BAD_ACCESS? Maybe Enable NSZOmbies to get a clearer message? From what I look, seems that your code compiles. But, it would help to give us what line is causing the issue...

Comment: i have navigation back button .i created UIpageviewcontroller.when i click back button then controller move back to privious view but controller go to menu and hang on same page .no error massage in log.

Comment: how to nil the back button

Comment: What do you mean, how to "nil the backbutton" ? Hide it? If yes, there are plenty question in SO asking how to do it.

Comment: Terminating in response to SpringBoard's termination. this error massage in log

Comment: Here we're talking! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10281160/terminating-in-response-to-springboards-termination

Comment: how to solve "Terminating in response to SpringBoard's termination" memory problem

Answer (score 0):

Try using this in your back button press event or code.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Customise your back button action, Try below code

```
 UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"backBtn.png"];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25);
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(GoBack) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarItem;
    [customBarItem release];
```

Call this function

```
-(IBAction)GoBack
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```